# Blogger Website Don't Send Messages From Contact Form, Contact Form not Working

Tags: javascript, css, templates, blogger

the contact form on my blogger page is no longer working because I switched to the new theme. I couldn't find the reason. I added a gadget to the sidemenu and its visibility is turned off, but the form that worked in the old theme no longer works in my new theme. Can you help me?

This is conctact us page:

> https://www.mrvancetti.com/p/iletisim.html

And this, code of form:

```
<form name="contact-form"><div class="datainput"><input class="validate" id="ContactForm1_contact-form-name" name="name" required="" type="text" value="" /> <span class="highlight"></span> <span class="bar"></span> <label>&nbsp;&nbsp;Ad Soyad</label> </div><div class="datainput"><input class="validate" id="ContactForm1_contact-form-email" name="email" required="" type="email" value="" /> <span class="highlight"></span> <span class="bar"></span> <label>&nbsp;&nbsp;E-posta</label> </div><div class="datainput"><textarea class="validate" cols="25" id="ContactForm1_contact-form-email-message" name="email-message" required="" rows="5"></textarea> <span class="highlight"></span> <span class="bar"></span> <label>&nbsp;&nbsp;Bilgi almak istediğiniz konuyu bize açıklayın :)</label> </div><input id="ContactForm1_contact-form-submit" type="button" value="Gönder" /> <div id="ContactForm1_contact-form-error-message"></div><div id="ContactForm1_contact-form-success-message"></div></form><script src="https://www.blogger.com/static/v1/widgets/2271878333-widgets.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <script type="text/javascript">

//<![CDATA[
if (typeof(BLOG_attachCsiOnload) != 'undefined' && BLOG_attachCsiOnload != null) { window['blogger_templates_experiment_id'] = "templatesV1";window['blogger_blog_id'] = '8194927727033356502';BLOG_attachCsiOnload(''); }_WidgetManager._Init('//www.blogger.com/rearrange?blogID\x3d8194927727033356502','//mrvancetti.com/','8194927727033356502');
_WidgetManager._RegisterWidget('_ContactFormView', new _WidgetInfo('ContactForm1', 'footer1', null, document.getElementById('ContactForm1'), {'contactFormMessageSendingMsg': '<span style="padding:5px 10px">Gönderiliyor...</span>', 'contactFormMessageSentMsg': '<span style="padding:5px 10px">Your message has been sent.</span>', 'contactFormMessageNotSentMsg': '<span style="padding:5px 10px">Message could not be sent. Please try again later.</span>', 'contactFormInvalidEmailMsg': '<span style="padding:5px 10px">A valid email address is required.</span>', 'contactFormEmptyMessageMsg': '<span style="padding:5px 10px">Message field cannot be empty.</span>', 'title': 'Contact Form', 'blogId': '8194927727033356502', 'contactFormNameMsg': 'Name', 'contactFormEmailMsg': 'Email', 'contactFormMessageMsg': 'Message', 'contactFormSendMsg': 'Send', 'submitUrl': 'https://www.blogger.com/contact-form.do'}, 'displayModeFull'));
//]]>

</script> <style scoped="scoped">
.datainput{float:none;position:relative;margin-bottom:45px;margin-right:10px}.datainput input,.datainput textarea{font-size:15px;padding:15px 0;display:block;width:100%;border:none;border-bottom:1px solid #ddd}.datainput input:focus,.datainput textarea:focus{outline:none}.datainput label{color:#999;font-size:15px;font-weight:400;position:absolute;pointer-events:none;left:0;top:10px;transition:.2s ease all}.datainput input:focus ~ label,.datainput input:valid ~ label,.datainput textarea:focus ~ label,.datainput textarea:valid ~ label{top:-20px;font-size:14px;color:#5264AE}.bar{position:relative;display:block;width:100%}.bar:before,.bar:after{content:'';height:2px;width:0;bottom:1px;position:absolute;background:#262421;transition:.2s ease all}.bar:before{left:50%}.bar:after{right:50%}.datainput input:focus ~ .bar:before,.datainput input:focus ~ .bar:after,.datainput textarea:focus ~ .bar:before,.datainput textarea:focus ~ .bar:after{width:50%}.highlight{position:absolute;height:50%;width:100px;top:25%;left:0;pointer-events:none;opacity:.5}.datainput input:focus ~ .highlight,.datainput textarea:focus ~ .highlight{animation:inputHighlighter .3s ease}.datainput input:focus ~ label,.datainput input:valid ~ label,.datainput textarea:focus ~ label,.datainput textarea:valid ~ label{top:-20px;font-size:13px;color:#262421}
input#ContactForm1_contact-form-email-message{height:150px}
input#ContactForm1_contact-form-submit{color:#fff!important;background:#262421;width: 100%;padding:15px 25px;border-radius:4px;border:none;outline:none;box-shadow:0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.16),0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.12);cursor:pointer;transition:all .4s ease-in-out;text-transform:uppercase;float:left;margin-top:15px}
input#ContactForm1_contact-form-submit:hover{box-shadow:0 8px 17px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19)}
#ContactForm1_contact-form-error-message{float:right;background:#D32F2F;color:#fff;font-size:13px;font-weight:700;border-radius:3px}#ContactForm1_contact-form-success-message{float:right;background:#4CAF50;color:#fff;font-size:13px;font-weight:700;border-radius:3px}
</style> <div class="clear"></div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
<br /><br />
```

I tried many ways on the internet but I could never get the blogger's own contact form to work.

Comment: It's happening because of the CORS poicy error. The https://www.blogger.com/contact-form.do does not allow cross domain AJAX requests.

Comment: I'm glad you found the error and thank you very much. So how can I solve this? Do I need to remove AJAX codes or what should I write? Thank you, sir.

Comment: You can try to use the normal HTML form instead of ajax request.
Ideally, since you are using a theme, it's better you raise a request with them.

Comment: Well, after making this form with HTML, won't I still need a submission process, so I won't be able to use the blogger's own contact form? Sorry, this is the first time I've encountered such a situation on blogger.

Comment: Honestly, I don't have much idea about blogger myself. I'm assuming that earlier your form was working because the form was HTML based and not AJAX based.